# World Wind Rendering

Tags: worldwind

I have a problem with World Wind and my English is not really good but you'll understand my problem with those two pictures :

[Here is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nO8Q.gif)

[Here is the same image on World Wind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEKOT.jpg)

I don't know why the image is "changed"...

Here is my code :

```
public class WorldWindTemplate extends ApplicationTemplate
{
    public WorldWindTemplate()
    {
        Configuration.setValue(AVKey.GLOBE_CLASS_NAME, EarthFlat.class.getName());

        app = new AppFrame();
    }

    public class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame
    {        
        private RenderableLayer coucheSP;

        public AppFrame()
        {
            super(true, true, false);

            coucheSP = new RenderableLayer();
            coucheSP.setName("SP");
            coucheSP.setPickEnabled(false);

            Shapefile shapeFile = new Shapefile(new File("shapefile.shp"));

            while (shapeFile.hasNext()) {
                ShapefileRecord record = shapeFile.nextRecord();        
                VecBuffer vectorBuffer = record.getPointBuffer(0);

                ShapeAttributes normalAttributes = new BasicShapeAttributes();
                normalAttributes.setOutlineOpacity(1);

                float[] ft = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
                Polygon polygon = new Polygon(vectorBuffer.getPositions());
                polygon.setTextureImageSource("echiquier.gif", ft, 4);
                polygon.setAttributes(normalAttributes);
                coucheSP.addRenderable(polygon);
            }

            //Closing shape file
            shapeFile.close();

            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), coucheSP);
            getWwd().getView().getGlobe().setElevationModel(new ZeroElevationModel());
        }
    }
}
```

In my shapefile, there is an entity with 4 angles that I use to create the polygon. And the shapefile is generated using QGIS. Actually, I really need to have the same image (and same pixel) showed in World Wind.

I tried to find other thread for this problem but I couldn't find anything...

I'm a beginner with World Wind and I'd appreciate it if you could give me some help or hint. If you need more information or didn't understand something, just tell me.

---

EDIT 30/07 :

I may have a hint, looks like it's because of the projection used in QGIS when I create the shapefile.

Does somebody know the projection I have to use (and supported by WorldWind) for France ? I tried some and they were not supported by World Wind.

```
gov.nasa.worldwind.exception.WWRuntimeException: Unsupported projection
gov.nasa.worldwind.Projection.Unknown
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.Shapefile.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.Shapefile.initializeFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.Shapefile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.Shapefile.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

caused by

```
Shapefile shapeFile = new Shapefile(new File("shapefile.shp"));
```

Comment: Try simply drawing the points in your shapefile with no image. Are they at the corners of your image? Perhaps the image is stretched because your polygon is stretched...